# Car subwoofer powered by mains voltage

Tags: transformer

I have a car active subwoofer, 550w RMS, 1600w peak, which I would like to use in my home, and power it from 220v mains.

~133A is a fairly large ask from a transformer, I think, and even 46A seems quite high. I have a couple of computer PSUs knocking about, and I was wondering would it be possible to use a pair of these to supply the power required? Would it be as simple as connecting the transformers in parallel, to supply the subwoofer, or do I require something more complex?

Edit:
 Ok, when I say power, I'm talking about the feed used to operate the sub/amp. The +12v terminal on the unit. I'm not talking about the signal input. The two wattage values, are whats printed on the underside of the sub. (as well as 4Ω impedance & 12v DC input)

The figures I was pulling out, in regards to current draw, were 1600w/12v = *133A* and 550w/12v = *45A*, perhaps I'm well wrong with these though?

---

Added:

As people seem to be having trouble understanding this material. and as it's not clear why they are, here is a summary.

- A piece of equipment is usually operated in a car and powered from the car's 12V battery supply.
- The equipments purpose is to deliver audio energy into a load - usually the very low frequency end of 'music'. (It's a powered amplifier and is usually called a "subwoofer" but that tends to confuse people - think of it as equipment that needs 12V power.
- The equipment's rating plate says that it's maximum power output level is 550 Watt RMS and that peak power output is 1600 Watt. The Watts is expressed in RMS power as it's an amplifier but we can think of this as DC load with fair chance of approximate correctness. Music ratings being what they are the true power MAY be lower or far lower, but start at the stated levels initially.

As M. Ohm says that I = Power/Volts, this suggests that
 at  550 W the current is P/V =  550/12 = 45.8A = 46A and
 at 1600 W the current is P/V = 1600/12 = 133A

The questioner wants to know how to power this equipment directly from an AC mains powered supply.

Comment: Huh?  RMS makes no sense applied to Watts.  You don't power a speaker from mains.  That would blow it out and emit the single line frequency if it could handle it.  I can't even guess where you got 133 and 46A from.  It is impossible to tell what is being asked here.

Comment: "active subwoofer" - this means a device that contains its own amplifier. Sounds like it's designed for 12V automotive power, and wants up to 133A at peak power (i.e., 1600W), and 46A for nominal continuous loads of 550W.

Comment: I think i know what he is asking.....but not sure. I know that you can hook up any 12V power supply to an audio amplifier made for cars and have it work as long as you meet the current requirements of the amp. My Amp that i have(500W mono) is rated at 12V and Peak current of up to 20A, so i do not know where you got those totals.  So could you please elaborate on your question a little more?

Comment: The question is clear but the data is suspect. 550 W RMS is a very very very very large amount of music powr, even allowing for subwoofer inefficiencies. It may be right but I'm amazed - BUT I have no practical experiences of such. I'd expect modern youth to all have smoking or flaming heads rather than just being deaf as happens now :-). | SO I'd first try measuring actual currents when used in an automotive situation. As simple as a shunt in the battery lead. A 133A shunt looks a little like a crowbar :-). eg 0.1V drop at 130 A = < 1 milliohm. 46A is doable with PC supplies.

Comment: At 12V using a full bridge you can get about 8V RMS so to get 500 Watts V^2/R = 600 so R ~= 0.1 ohm. If you have higher speaker imeddances you either have a higher supply voltage (likely) or output transformer (unlikely) or magic.  Chances are you have an internal DCDC converter making 30 to 40 VDC. Popowering that directly from mains is much more attractive. Must rush ... later

Comment: @Russell: Your interpretation of the question does seem to be mostly consistant, but then what is this talk of a "transformer"?  Also "RMS Watts" makes no sense.  Apparently he wants to power a *amplifier*, not a subwoofer.

Comment: @RussellMcMahon: Ok, so you think there may be a converter inside the unit, to up the voltage to something easier to work with? I'll see if there is. Also, thanks clarification edits too.

Comment: @OlinLathrop: Yea, sorry my bad with the phrasing/terminology. I'm looking to power the amp built into the unit ('active subwoofer'), which in turn will drive the actual subwoofer. I require the transformer+rectifier device(which I've just called transformer above), to convert 220v AC (mains) to 12v DC (car).

Comment: @Jasper: No, you want a *power supply* to convert 220V AC to 12V DC.  That will likely have a transformer inside it somewhere, but that is a hidden implementation detail.  It will probably have a FET switch inside too, but you wouldn't call it a "FET switch" either.  By specifically saying you wanted a "tranformer", you were actually asking for something else, which didn't make sense in addition.  Always stick to what you actually know in a question.

Comment: I dont know a great deal about volts, watts, amps so I may be wrong but I understood that audio watts were different to electrical watts. I wasn't going to say because I think im probley wrong but I have a 400w rms 1200w peak sub and I have run it full pelt of a 17ah lead acid car jump starter for a good 45 mins. Also the power wire that came with the sub from halfords has an inline fuse rated at 20 amps. Therefore if my sub was to draw 25 amps or 40 amps i would have thought it would blow. Also the gauge and length of power cable sold with these subs couldnt possibly hold the voltage up high

Comment: I just got to ask: at how insane levels you are going to listen music? You don't need 500 Watts for that! Let's take a pretty normal low-end speaker, it will have a sensitivity of 80 dB per one Watt measured 1 meter (3ft) away from the speaker, so at 1 Watt of continuous music power you get 80 dB of sound power. A sound that is double as loud requires double the Watts and that is 3dB more. Double that again, and you end up with 4 Watts to produce 86 dB. Seriously, that's louder than one lawnmower, and it's pretty uncomfortable being indoors 1 meter away from such volume levels.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is only one good reason to power a 500+ Watt car amp from AC mains: to save money by using what you have.  From an electrical and practical point of view, it's silly.

Assuming you want to save money then the best way would be to use a car battery plus battery charger. The battery provides energy storage for the peaks but the charger keeps it going. There are lots of things wrong with this approach. The most important one is dealing with the potential for the battery to vent corrosive gases. But it will provide 1600 Watts for short times. Another issue is the cost of a battery and charger could cost as much as the correct solution-- unless you have it already.

The correct solution is to buy a real amp that runs off of the AC mains. It will be plenty powerful, have better audio quality, and be more reliable.  Something like the QSC G5 or G7 amp. (Disclaimer : I work for QSC, so I'm biased!)

Comment: yea, this is exactly it. I got the unit for next to nothing, and would like to keep the setup as close to that figure as possible :) from what I understand from your above content, its not really practical for me to do that, and it sounds like i'm trying to do a round peg, and a square hole.

Comment: Yup, its not practical. You wouldn't like the results anyway as car amps have a lot of distortion compared to normal amps.

Comment: @DavidKessner - are the power levels quoted real Watts? eg typically is such an amp liable to need 500W at 12VDC? And what sort of internal rail voltages doe it use and how dies it generate them?

Comment: Yes, the Watts are real,  but the 1600 Watt peak will only happen for a short time (and the time probably isn't spec'd).  Another issue is car amps are usually spec'd as "Max power at 10% THD+N" while other amps might be at 1% or even 0.1%.  You'd never hear 10% over the road noise but at home you would. All amps are class-d-ish, so probably 85-90% efficient.  Internally it is a boost switcher to get the main power rail (probably 80v) followed by the main amp.

Comment: Just to be clear, thus amp might be 10% THD at 550 Watts, but only 1% at 350 Watts.  The THD will drop quickly as the output level goes down. The same amp could be sold as a 350 Watt amp in a more critical market.

Comment: @jasper - the correct solution is exactly as DK says; for the price of a 12V supply capable of powering your automotive amp, you probably could just get one designed to run from mains directly.

Answer (score 4):

Sounds like you need a 12V supply that can source at least 46A continuously (for the 550W), with capability to give out 133A for brief periods of time (for the 1600W). That's a lot of juice at 12V.

Computer power supplies are what's known as 'switching' regulated power supplies. They are a fair bit more complicated than transformers, which are relatively simple devices. You can't just parallel computer PSUs, because tiny differences in their regulators' voltages will cause them to battle each other.

If you can't find a commercial 220V to 12V supply that has the necessary current rating, you could always keep a car battery topped up with an automotive battery charger, and just drive the unit from the battery. After all, it was designed to run from a 12V battery.

Comment: I did look for a transformer that would output at 12v, but nothing came near the current requirements I _think_ it requires(I could be wrong with the current calc though). Would a battery be safe? Gas buildup and indoors etc.

Comment: @jasper - a transformer by itself will give you 12V AC, but what you need is DC.

Comment: As for current requirements, you might be able to run with a lower current supply if you keep the signal level low enough. Of course, if something extra loud comes along in your signal, you might toast your supply, unless it has a fuse or breaker.

Comment: FYI!! As someone who has done it before.. Paralleling Computer PSU's is NOT a smart idea. Unless you go to great lengths to balance the load. Else one PSU get's pulled more than another. I thought I was a clever teenager until the switching MOSFETS went up in LITERAL flames in the floor. Not good.. Not good at all....

Answer (score 0):

Affordable (30 dollar Chinese) switching-type power supply unit will deliver 12 volts DC up to 20 amps - then the fuse blows.  That current represents 240 watts, which will translate to about 220 watts maximum audio with an efficient amplifier (rms watts not the meaningless peak value).
On a big speaker chassis with good magnet that's pretty loud in the home.  I use such a rig for organ, down to 16Hz where of course human ears are relatively deaf.   Not safe to parallel switching power units, as already said here, but you might parallel several identical 12 volt traditional lighting transformers (scrap heap stuff) to get the amperage.  Very big and heavy.
Of course, you'd need a rectifier to convert AC to DC (cheap 60 amp bridge is good) and chunky smoothing capacitors.
I have not actually tried multiple trannies - and having written all this, probably won't!

Answer (score -1):

What about a Computer PSU in parallel with a small car battery? This should handle all but the largest of amplifiers, and have enough reserve to handle bass hits of several times the PSU's rating without bogging down.